# Qt dynamic layout

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm trying to implement a layout like the file explorer in thumbnails mode. The items are in a grid with fixed distance between them and when you resize the main window, the items are re-positioned to fit.

For example, on a small window you have:

```
i1 i2 i3
j1 j2 j3
k1 k2 k3
```

But when the window is wider, the items become:

```
i1 i2 i3 j1
j2 j3 k1 k2
k3
```

And if you make the window even wider, the items become:

```
i1 i2 i3 j1 j2
j3 k1 k2 k3
```

I'm trying to implement it as simply as possible, maybe using only the default classes?...

The HBoxLayout doesn't overflow if you put an infinite number of items; they just line up infinitely.

The GridLayout cannot help, because after you put the items first, after a window resize, you have to clean the layout, re-calculate the number of items, re-populate the layout with the new order. It doesn't reposition the items automatically.

Another way could be to put items in a TableWidget, Qt3 style. But that's just the same; after window resize, you have calculate how many items fit in the new window, clean the table and re-populate.

There is also the fix position method. You put the items in fixed position and move them after each window resize... it's a headache.

Did anyone try something like that - an explorer or image viewer?  How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to look into doing something like the [FlowLayout](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-flowlayout.html) from the example set.  Note that there is a [python port](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/blobs/07c17233c1d3cb0f7a4b6e0bbfcc641ef4b4f5a4/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py) of it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want ! From what i understand, it cannot be done simpler than that ...